# How to set up website periodic tasks?

Tags: web-services, web-applications

I'm not sure if the topic is appropiate to the question... Anyway, suppose I've a website, done with PHP or JSP and a cheap hosting with limited functionalities. More precisely I don't own the server and I can't run daemons or services at my will. Now I want to run periodic (say every minute or two) tasks to do certain statistics. They are likely to be time consuming so I just can't repeat the calculation for every user accessing a page. I could do the calculation once when a user loads a page and I calculate that enough time has passed, but in this situation if the calculation gets very long the response time may be excessive and timeout (it's not likely I don't mean to run such long task, but I'm considering the worst case).

So given these costraints, what solutions would you suggest?

Comment: open question... both java and php are considered albeit you could suggest yours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to use crontab, you're going to have to know a bit more to execute your PHP scripts from them. Depending on if your PHP executes as CGI or an apache module has an effect. There's a good article on how to do this at:

http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/running-php-scripts-with-cron/

If you don't have access to crontab on your hosting provider (find a new one) there are other options. For example:

http://www.setcronjob.com/

Will call a script on your site, remotely every X period .. you have to renew it once a month I think. If you take their paid service ($5/year according to the front page) I *think* the jobs you set up last until you cancel them or your paid term runs out.

Answer (score 2):

Each cheap hosting will have support of `crontabs`. Check out the hosting packages first.
If not, load in the page, and launch the task by AJAX. This way your response time doesn't suffer and you do in a different thread the work.

Comment: Hmmm. not sure as the page needs all the stats done when it loads up. anyway the crontabs seems interesting. Will it run php scripts?

Comment: yes, `crontabs` runs anything the server can run(scripts) in your directory

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you could just create a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html). It can create a background thread that will perform a given function every so often.

My preference would be to start the Timer object in a ContextListener.contextInitialized() method, but you may have a more appropriate place.